# How to set an angular mat radio button to selected by default?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I would like to ask , I am using the update angular verion. I was trying to set a mat radio button as selected by default , I tried using [checked]="true" but it does not seem to work . Any idea ? or any update on the syntax? Thanks.

[image]

#Code

```
 <mat-radio-group name="isSubleaseCoterminusWithMasterLease" (change)="onChangeSubleaseCoterminus($event)" [(ngModel)]="dealDispositionFormFields.isSubleaseCoterminusWithMasterLease">
            <div class="flex" style="justify-content: space-between;">
              <div class="deal-form-btn-group w-46-per" [ngClass]="{'v-bg-color': dealDispositionFormFields.isSubleaseCoterminusWithMasterLease === 'No'}"  >
                <div class="deal-form-btn-group-radio">
                  <mat-radio-button
                  [checked]='true'
                  *ngIf="dealDispositionFormFields.isSubleaseCoterminusWithMasterLease === 'No' else notSubleaseCoterminusWithMasterLease"    
                    color="accent"
                    [value]="'No'">
                      <span class="alter-text-color">No</span>
                  </mat-radio-button>
                  <ng-template #notSubleaseCoterminusWithMasterLease>
                    <mat-radio-button
                     [checked]="true"
                      [value]="'No'">
                        No
                    </mat-radio-button>
                  </ng-template>
                </div>
              </div> 
            </div>
          </mat-radio-group>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ngModel` inside the `<mat-radio-group>` tag this as follows

```
<mat-radio-group  [(ngModel)]="selected">
```

And in your .ts file

```
selected: string;  
ngOnInit(){    
   this.selected = "No";
}
```

Here is a working example:  [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tcrljm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)